# Android Studio not recognize R class in Muzei Live Wallpaper?

Tags: android, android-studio, muzei

I'm trying to import Muzei Live Wallpaper in Android Studio.
I downloaded this project from this link in github http://github.com/romannurik/muzei.
I copy it in android studio but I get below errors

[image]

R class also not recognize. 
can anyone help me to run this project in android studio?

Comment: try differents way to open the project, import/open to generate all the files that must be generated

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the project and is working fine for me.

Comment: Are you run it in android studio?

Comment: Yes, android studio 1.5.1
I got the code from github and openned with android studio (File / Open ) then I could build/rebuild and run the code on my device.